# cloudinary.api.resources is raising MaxRetryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, cloudinary

When I use the `cloudinary.api.resources` in my local. It returns the required information successfully.

But when I upload it to my hosting it raises a `MaxRetryError`.

This is my code:

```py
cloudinary==1.8.0


import cloudinary
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
result = cloudinary.api.resources(api_key='my_api_key', api_secret='my_api_secret', cloud_name='my_cloud')
```

Any idea what can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to get the resources on your cloudinary account:

```
import cloudinary
import cloudinary.uploader
import cloudinary.api

cloudinary.config( 
  cloud_name = "sample", 
  api_key = "874837483274837", 
  api_secret = "a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1" 
)

result = cloudinary.api.resources()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently the urllib3 version, was having conflict internally with the cloudinary method. I had to downgrade it.